# Has MapReduce been used to make Stackoverflow?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow

Has [MapReduce](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MapReduce) been used to make Stackoverflow site?

If yes, what did they do by using MapReduce?

Comment: Belongs on meta. Also, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10369/what-was-stack-overflow-built-with

Comment: I had already seen it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the map reduce algorithm was not used.  We manage to keep our datasets fairly small and SQL efficient so we don't really need sharding for SO yet